# Does GraphQLConfiguration need to specify external mutations/queries as well as served ones?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I'm trying to augment a graphql server by calling other graphql services for added functionality. But now with new calls to these external services, the GraphQLSchema bean won't build. The first mutation under "type MutationType" starts a cascade of errors.

Do the external graphql services have to be defined in the schema.graphqls file? I have separate .graphqls files that contain the mutation, input, and returned fields to be used in an Http call too the "/graphql" endpoint.

All ideas appreciated.